# Error:406 not acceptable

Tags: htaccess

I have a wodpress site, and I have submitted it to google webmaster tools. When I search on google by my site name, the results come, and on clicking the searched result, I can open the website on my PC. But when doing the same thing on my mobile, i get this

```
Error 406: Not accebtable
```

How can can resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently with this 406 Not Acceptable error occurring when trying to update permalinks in WordPress. I also had the same problem when submitting any changes to the editor, etc. Google Webmaster tools would yield the same result.

The solution is to disable the mod_security firewall within your `.htaccess` file.

My fix was to install a plugin called "WP Htaccess Editor" (free WP plugin), then update the `.htaccess` file to the following, between the "Begin WordPress" and "End WordPress" tags:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A `406 Not Acceptable` HTTP error usually indicates that the content type of your webpage is not in the `Accept` request header that your browser sent to the webserver.

When you load a website, your browser sends a `Accept` header with the content types that it will accept, like `text/html` or `text/xml`. But when the webserver sends a format your browser doesn't accept, it will give you a 406 HTTP error.

My guess is that a plugin or theme is changing the content type header, or your phone's browser is acting weird.

Comment: Really I can't thank you!! All other answers are trying to tell a solution without defining the problem.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while using WooCommerce API for Node JS.
I just changed the verb put to post and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here was fixed using this lines on .htaccess file (public_html)

```
   <IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngineOff
SecFilterScanPOSTOff
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you add more to your answer to describe why this fixed this problem and what it does?