# Get "HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable" when accesing my website with Delphi Indy Control

Tags: http

I am usig Delphi XE10.3 + TIdHTTP(Indy)(10.6.2) control to visit websites.

When visiting my website via Get method, I will get an exception "HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable".

I am not sure whether it is a problem of my program or my website, so I try to use my program to visit another website https://www.wordpress.com and this time I will NOT get the exception.

Therefore, this is a problem of my website so I ask here.

Based on [Error:406 not acceptable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183067/error406-not-acceptable), "A 406 Not Acceptable HTTP error usually indicates that the content type of your webpage is not in the Accept request header that your browser sent to the webserver.", so is there a way to know what is "the content type of my website"?

Thanks

Comment: Make a request without an [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header, or `Accept: */*`, and see what the `Content-Type:` header returned is. It'll almost certainly be `text/html`. I'd guess your web client is sending a strange Accept line, or it's expecting a JSON endpoint and sending `Accept: application/json`, or something similar. Can you remove the Accept header from your client?

Comment: @Rup, Thank you, but my Accept is "text/html, \*/\*". I have changed it to "\*/\*" and try again, but still get the same exception

Comment: OK, I'd guess it's not the Accept header then. Is there anything in your server error logs why it's rejecting the connection? You could also try overriding the User-Agent with a browser-like User-Agent string in case your server is configured to reject scrapers somehow.

Comment: @Rup, My user agent is "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)", which value should I try to make it looks like a browser?

Comment: @Rup, My problem is solved, I have changed the user agent to "Mozilla/3.0" and then it works.